# Как правильно запускать pgbadger?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql

Я пробовал запустить pgbadger на csv файле `pgbadger /var/log/postgresql/query.csv` и получил ошибку

```
FATAL: unable to detect log file format from /var/log/postgresql/query.csv, please use -f option.
    - Error at line 17028
```

Так же пробовал `pgbadger -f csv /var/log/postgresql/query.csv` но на выходе получается вот такой бесполезный html, при том что в файле 22к строк логов. Как правильно запускать pgbadger? Утилиту взял с репозитория ubuntu20.04
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]